# Excel macro to insert certain characters into column

Tags: excel, vba

Im currently using this. while this works for now. Im looking to add code that allows me replace everything in that column. Not just limited to only replacing the 0 or one word.

```
.AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:="0"
Columns("F").replace What:="0", Replacement:="Not Needed", Lookat:=xlPart, searchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, Searchformat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilterMode = False
```

Comment: You told us what you want to do, but what exactly is the question here?

Comment: The question is. is it possible to be able to do that and if so. what would the code look like?

Comment: What you said is quite confusing. Could it be clearer?

Comment: Did you mean that what you want is : (1) filter a table on certain column with certain criteria (2) when it's in the filtered condition - change whatever value in the visible rows of the table to "X" ? Example : the table is 3 columns from cell A1 to C11, the first row is the header. cells A2:A10 and B2:B10 data is a string (no need to know what is the value of the string, but for example the strings are xxx01 to xxx10 from row 2 to row 10 in column A and column B). In C2:C6 the value is 0, in C7:C11 the value is 1. (continue)

Comment: Filter column C with 0, then change whatever is seen (except the header) in the filtered table to "X". When the filter is clear, what you see in A2:A6, B2:B6 and C2:C6 are "X", in A7:A11 and B7:B11 is xxx06 to xxx10, and in C7:C11 is 1. Is that what you mean ?

Comment: Yes @karma that is correct. Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
Sub test()
Dim rg As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        Set rg = .Range("A1", .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) 'change as needed
            With rg
                .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=0", Operator:=xlAnd 'change as needed
                .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "X"
                .AutoFilter
            End With
    End With
End Sub
```